# add feature raw request to python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I am trying to add feature to this code to export HTTP request as raw request in output text file,
Original python file

```
import json
import requests

import arjun.core.config as mem
from arjun.core.utils import populate

from arjun.core.utils import create_query_string

def json_export(result):
    """
    exports result to a file in JSON format
    """
    with open(mem.var['json_file'], 'w+', encoding='utf8') as json_output:
        json.dump(result, json_output, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def burp_export(result):
    """
    exports results to Burp Suite by sending request to Burp proxy
    """
    proxies = {
        'http': 'http://' + mem.var['burp_port'],
        'https': 'http://' + mem.var['burp_port']
    }
    for url, data in result.items():
        if data['method'] == 'GET':
            requests.get(url, params=populate(data['params']), headers=data['headers'], proxies=proxies, verify=False)
        elif data['method'] == 'POST':
            requests.post(url, data=populate(data['params']), headers=data['headers'], proxies=proxies, verify=False)
        elif data['method'] == 'JSON':
            requests.post(url, json=populate(data['params']), headers=data['headers'], proxies=proxies, verify=False)

def text_export(result):
    """
    exports results to a text file, one url per line
    """
    with open(mem.var['text_file'], 'w+', encoding='utf8') as text_file:
        for url, data in result.items():
            clean_url = url.lstrip('/')
            if data['method'] == 'JSON':
                text_file.write(clean_url + '\t' + json.dumps(populate(data['params'])) + '\n')
            else:
                query_string = create_query_string(data['params'])
                if '?' in clean_url:
                    query_string = query_string.replace('?', '&', 1)
                if data['method'] == 'GET':
                    text_file.write(clean_url + query_string + '\n')
                elif data['method'] == 'POST':
                    text_file.write(clean_url + '\t' + query_string + '\n')

def exporter(result):
    """
    main exporter function that calls other export functions
    """
    if mem.var['json_file']:
        json_export(result)
    if mem.var['text_file']:
        text_export(result)
    if mem.var['burp_port']:
        burp_export(result)
```

I have commented `text_file.write(clean_url + '\t' + query_string + '\n')`
and replace it with

```
print('{}\n{}\r\n{}\r\n\r\n{}'.format(
                        result.method + ' ' + result.url,
                        '\r\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in result.headers.items()),
                        result.body,
                        ))
```

to enhance POST request output as raw but there is something wrong that I am missing.
Any help !!!

BTW there is another file which act as parameters brute force

Comment: Can you add what you mean with `something wrong`? Include desired behaviour and acutal behaviour/error message you are getting

Comment: @FlyingTeller error as following ```File "__main__.py", line 186, in main
    exporter(final_result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/arjun-2.1.4-py3.8.egg/arjun/core/exporter.py", line 63, in exporter
    text_export(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/arjun-2.1.4-py3.8.egg/arjun/core/exporter.py", line 49, in text_export
    result.method + ' ' + result.url,
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'method```

Comment: is there some thing i need to define before call it in code?

Comment: @FlyingTeller i am tring to debug this so i added `print(result)` instead of my editing code so it prints ```{'http://www.example.com/': {'params': ['goButton', 'searchFor'], 'method': 'POST', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'close', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'}}}``` so i need to figure out reformat this output to raw request

Comment: Please add this information to your question instead of as comment. Looks to me though that `result` is a dictionary, so `result.method` does not work, but `result["method"]` should work

Comment: @FlyingTeller i got ```result.[method] + ' ' + result.["url"],
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax``` it is not accepting `[`

Comment: `result.[method]` should be `result["method"]` (no period and added `""`) and `result.["url"]` should be `result["url"]` (no period)

Comment: @FlyingTeller ```File "__main__.py", line 190, in <module>
    main()
  File "__main__.py", line 186, in main
    exporter(final_result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/arjun-2.1.4-py3.8.egg/arjun/core/exporter.py", line 66, in exporter
    text_export(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/arjun-2.1.4-py3.8.egg/arjun/core/exporter.py", line 50, in text_export
    result['method'] + ' ' + result['url'],
KeyError: 'method'```

Comment: Nowhere in your posted code do you define `result` -- but the error has to do with `result`. Please post a [mcve], not a code fragment that has the property that the readers have to guess how important variables are defined and how the functions which are throwing the error are called.